# a combinatorial identity related to log(1+x)

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

A book says that
the identity
$$
\log((1+x)(1+y))=\log(1+x) + \log(1+y)
$$
is a formal consequence of the series expansion
$$
\log(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \cdots.
$$

Upon expanding, this would follow from the following combinatorial identity
$$
\sum_{a=0}^m (-1)^a \frac{(m+n-a-1)!}{(m-a)!(n-a)!a!} = 0, 
$$
where $1\leq m\leq n$. I don't see how to prove the identity.

Just wonder if someone has a proof for this, thanks.

Comment: I am confused by the posting.  $~\log(a \times b) = \log(a) + \log(b).~$  Doesn't this insight resolve the question?  Unknown why a Math book would veer away from this basic identity of logarithms.

Comment: @user2661923: here we are considering the logarithm as a formal power series. You can still deduce this fact from the corresponding fact about the analytic logarithm but it's a little less obvious from first principles, and in any case it's interesting to see what can be done avoiding analysis. For example this lets us deduce things about how the logarithm behaves in a Banach algebra or over the $p$-adic numbers where it's less obvious that the behavior is being controlled by the usual logarithm.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Very interesting comment, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a combinatorial proof, say, using inclusion-exclusion on some set? Maybe you can consider a related combinatorial identity, $$\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-y}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+\log\left(\frac{1}{1-y}\right).$$

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein It would be nice to know a proof of the combinatorial identity in my post, or some interpretation of it, since technically the log identity is a proof of it. (I also don't quite see how the $-\log(1-x)$ helps. It seems to be just a rewriting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a cleaner and much more conceptual way to prove this. $\log (1 + x)$, as a formal power series, can be defined as the unique formal power series $f(x)$ satisfying

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x}, f(0) = 0.$$

We now compute, via the formal chain rule, that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \log \left( (1 + x)(1 + y) \right) = \frac{1 + y}{(1 + x)(1 + y)} = \frac{1}{1 + x}$$

which is the same as $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \log (1 + x) + \log (1 + y) \right)$. So, these two expressions, as formal power series in $x$ with coefficients in formal power series in $y$, have the same derivative, meaning their difference is a "constant," i.e. a formal power series in $y$ only. And substituting $x = 0$ shows that this difference is zero.

A very similar argument can be used to prove that $\exp(x + y) = \exp(x) \exp(y)$ as formal power series using the fact that $\exp(x)$ is the unique power series satisfying $f'(x) = f(x), f(0) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Qiaochu. I see, so the differentiation is helping here, and it follows from the series expansion. But $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x) \exp(y)$ can be checked by binomial theorem directly, and I was hoping for something similar.

On the other hand, it seems that any expression such as $\exp(\log(1+x)) = 1+x$ is leading to messy combinatorial formulas, which are true, but not easy to see directly.